# Pass a function's value to controller in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using map picker function in my flutter app which I am calling somewhere below in my code where I want to pass the value of the selected map location via the function to the provider controller but I am stuck with the passing function value problem I don't know how to do it.

Here's my code of function

```
 showPlacePicker() async {
    LocationResult result = await Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) =>
            PlacePicker("MY GOOGLE MAPS API KEY HERE")));
    print(result);
  }
```

Here I am calling the function and I want the controller on this textformfield

```
   Container(
                  width: 270,
                  child: TextFormField(
                    cursorColor: Colors.white,
                    style: TextStyle(color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                          borderSide: BorderSide(),
                        ),
                        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                          borderSide: BorderSide(
                            width: 2.0,
                          ),
                        ),
                        hintText: "Select Location",
                        hintStyle: TextStyle(
                          color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                          fontFamily: "San Francisco",
                        )),
                    onTap: () async {
                      showPlacePicker();
                    },
                    // controller: provider.controllerText,
                  ),
                ),
```

Answer (score 0):

return the result from the function instead of printing it

```
 Future<LocationResult>  showPlacePicker() async {
    LocationResult result = await Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) =>
            PlacePicker("MY GOOGLE MAPS API KEY HERE")));
    return result;
  }
```

and in the onTap you should do something like this:

```
 onTap: () async {
      showPlacePicker().then((result) {
      yourTextFieldController.text = result.something // something like this but I don't really know what the result object has as a parameter so you should do it.
});
  },
```

!!!!!but don't forget to return something from the PlacePicker when popping back
it should be like this

```
Navigator.pop(context, result);
```

Comment: That's really helpful. The result is giving picked location I'm passing it to controller to save in firebase but It seems that is not working i've isEmpty validation on the controller and even upon selecting it is giving error of being empty and I'm confused here with the navigator pop

Comment: I can't put Navigator.pop on PlacePicker because its a package and it has its own file/screen so how can I bring the selected result and pass it to controller the onTap isn't working for me